# ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I try to include any dependency Build Fails, I have tried many solutions such ass clean project and rebuild, invalidate cache even reinstalled android studio
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx6Go.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your project level build.gradle file

`maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }`